# Displaying date only and not date & time

Tags: vb.net

I have a code that displays a date on a msgbox but I only want the date, not the time. Here's my code:

```
    Private Sub Button8_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click

        MsgBox(Date.Now)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use one of the following:

- [`MsgBox(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString())`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring(v=vs.110).aspx)
  This returns the culture-specific short string representation of the date part of the `DateTime` instance. (for en-us, it would be month/day/year - 11/26/2017)
- [`MsgBox(DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString())`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolongdatestring(v=vs.110).aspx)
  This returns the culture-specific long string representation of the date part of the `DateTime` instance. (for en-us, it would be "Day-of-week, month day-of-month, year" Sunday, Numvember 26, 2017)
- [`MsgBox(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx)
  This returns a custom format string representation of the date part of the `DateTime` instance. (26/11/2017)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to help :-)